# Leer con SDK Firebase en Flutter vs API REST

Tags: firebase, api, flutter, sdk

Necesito migrar de API REST Firebase a SDK de Firebase en Flutter con el objetivo de aprovechar la funcionalidad Offline Persistence en Firebase.

El código que me funciona actualmente (API REST) hace la consulta a la base de datos usando un GET y retorna una lista del tipo de objeto que estoy usando (lo llamé EstanqueModel), tal como se ve a continuación:

```
Future<List<EstanqueModel>> cargarEstanques(String idEmpresa) async {

    final url ='$_url/empresas/$idEmpresa/estanques.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';
    final resp = await http.get(url); // May query in API REST of Firebase

    final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
    final List<EstanqueModel> estanque = new List(); 

    if (decodedData == null) return [];
    if (decodedData['error'] != null) return []; 

    decodedData.forEach((id, esta){ 
      final estaLoteTemp = EstanqueModel.fromJson(esta);
      estaLoteTemp.idEstanque = id; 
      estanque.add(estaLoteTemp);
    });

    return estanque;
  }
```

Intenté hacer lo mismo, tal vez de una forma no tan óptima usando el SDK, con el siguiente código:

```
Future<List> cargarEstanques(String idEmpresa) async {

final List<EstanqueModel> estanque = new List(); 

Query resp = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
  .child('empresas')
  .child(idEmpresa)
  .child('estanques');

return resp.once().then((snapshot) {
  print('Data: ${snapshot.value}');
  final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = json.decode(snapshot.value);
    if (decodedData == null) return [];
    if (decodedData['error'] != null) return []; 

    decodedData.forEach((id, esta){
      final estaLoteTemp = EstanqueModel.fromJson(esta);
      estaLoteTemp.idEstanque = id;

      estanque.add(estaLoteTemp);
    }
  );
  return estanque;
}
); 
}
```

La consola no me nuestra ningún error, pero no estoy obteniendo la lectura a la base. En el StreamBuilder que implementé para la interfaz de usuario, puedo notar que el connectionstate del AsyncSnapshot se mantiene a la espera (waiting) de la información y nunca le llega por lo que no muestra ninfún resultado en pantalla (no .hasdata).

Alguien me puede recomendar cuál sería la forma más fácil y eficiente de convertir el código que tengo basado en APIs al código basado en SDK?

**ACTUALIZACION**

Después de hacer algunas pruebas, Firebase me indicó que había un problema en la iniciación de la base de datos,así que hice el paso a paso de las indicaciones y ya pude ejecutar el código y hacer las pruebas.

El error que está apareciendo al ejecutar es el siguiente:

> _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Cuando hago un breakpoint, puedo observar que snapshot.values está trayendo directamente un mapa con los diferentes items del tipo EstanqueModel, así que el problema puede estar al llamar el json.decode. El mapa que está en snapshot.values luce así:

```
0:"-MD7b_saAgbsHSriYUKT" -> Map (12 items)
 key:"-MD7b_saAgbsHSriYUKT"
 value:Map (12 items)
   0:"nombreRef" -> "U2"
   1:"estado" -> "actual"
   2:"idEmpresa" -> "-MD5t6MY6fGbcMGuk"
   3:"foto" -> "ruta/foto"
   4:"ancho" -> 58.0
   5:"tipoInfra" -> ""
   6:"loteActual" -> Map (18 items)
   7:"largo" -> 588.0
   8:"nombre" -> "Estanque XYZ"
   9:"alto" -> 6.0
   10:"ubicacion" -> ""
   11:"refLoteActual" -> "KS1003"
 1:"-MD5tS4QONdvPeCsaJcK" -> Map (11 items)
 2:"-MD5uJaHsMLJ0AIVuDuj" -> Map (12 items)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que es una petición asíncrona y no la estás esperando, solo debes cambiar el `then` por un `await`, de la siguiente manera:

```dart
   Future<List> cargarEstanques(String idEmpresa) async {
    final List<EstanqueModel> estanque = new List();

    Query resp = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('empresas').child(idEmpresa).child('estanques');
    final snapshot = await resp.once();
    final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);
      if (decodedData == null) return [];
      if (decodedData['error'] != null) return [];

      decodedData.forEach((id, esta) {
        final estaLoteTemp = EstanqueModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(esta));
        estaLoteTemp.idEstanque = id;

        estanque.add(estaLoteTemp);
      });
      return estanque;
  }
```

Comment: Aún no he podido avanzar con la prueba. Me salió un mensaje respecto a que el problema era la instalación del SDK del Firebase. Procedí a hacer la configuración  de los archivos conforme la guía de Firebase. Una vez lo hice, subo la aplicación, hago los cambios de código que tu recomiendas y me aparece que el acceso es denegado (DatabaseError(-3, Permission denied, )). Allí me pregunto si para usar los comandos de lectura del SDK también se requiere que la autenticación se haga por el mismo SDK?

Comment: Así es, es de acuerdo a como configuras las reglas de la database, creo que por default te pide que estes authenticado con el sdk.

Comment: Gracias, como workaround mientras resuelvo la autenticación, puse la DB pública e intenté probar el código que me recomiendas. El error que aparece en la línea de la definición del decodedData es el siguiente: _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Comment: Pinta el snapshot value y fijate que retorna

Comment: Está retornando un Mapa con los items adentro, cada uno de los cuales tiene un key y un objeto del tipo EstanqueModel

Comment: Ponlo en tu pregunta

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta. Para tu referencia, cuando ejecuto el código que me compartiste, el error exacto es... _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Comment: Si ya veo es un error al parsear tus datos,  ya es un error màs bàsico, el error principal te lo di en mi respuesta. Para lo otro revisa “Parseando JSON complejo en Flutter” by CarlosMillan https://link.medium.com/SehNof4Fr8

Comment: Hola, gracias por el link, lo leí  e hice algunas pruebas buscando convertir los modelos y los tipos, pero no funciona. Tanto el código que incluí originalmente como el código que tu indicas tienen un error similar, dado que no están haciendo el mapping correctamente.

Comment: en mi respuesta, agrega esto   final snapshot = await resp.once(); print(snapshot.value) y pon el valor que te aparece, para saber que valor te retorna antes de decodificarlo

Comment: Hola... lo incluí como una propuesta de edición a tu respuesta para que quepan los caracteres. Es el resultado de     print('Data await: ${snapshot.value}');

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Comment: Aparece el siguiente error: The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: actualizado, no necesitas el jsonDecode porque ya viene un map

Comment: Ahora pasa la linea del decodedData y vuelve a aparecer el mismo error encima de la variable llamada "esta". El error que aparece dice _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Comment: Lo has implementado igual que ni respuesta?

Comment: Igual. Te incluí un pantallazo con el error que marca

Comment: revisa mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: Uffff.... funcionó!!!!! Muchas gracias. Es curioso que el SDK termina dando más vueltas que el mismo API REST. Será que estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: jaja si un poco, más que todo porque el dato que retorna es un Map, ya no necesitas el decode

Comment: Bien, muchas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una opción más simple sin usar el await y aprovehando que el snapshot.value es iterable en sí mismo...

```
Future<List<EstanqueModel>> cargarEstanques(String idEmpresa) async {

  final List<EstanqueModel> estanque = new List(); 

  Query resp = db.child('empresas').child(idEmpresa).child('estanques');

  return resp.once().then((snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.value == null) return [];
      if (snapshot.value['error'] != null) return []; 

      snapshot.value.forEach((id, esta){
        final estaLoteTemp = EstanqueModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(esta));
        estaLoteTemp.idEstanque = id;

        estanque.add(estaLoteTemp);
      });
      return estanque;
  }); 
}
```

Como ven, es una optimización de la solución de @diegoveloper sin usar **await**, que [según @ishwar.chandra en Medium](https://medium.com/@ishwar.chandra/when-you-use-offline-persistence-in-firestore-dont-use-transactions-or-await-for-response-df8a45ececc2) no se debería usar para conservarlas propiedades offline de Firebase:

> when you use offline persistence in Firestore, don’t use Transactions
> or await for response.